# How to deal with random order of Set in test case?

Tags: java, unit-testing

In my test cases, I use assertEquals() to make a unit test. The problem is that the value of this assertion comes from a HashSet, where the order is random. So each time when I run the test case, my assertions may fail due to the different string representation value of HashSet.

In order to deal with this, I am thinking to use a LinkedHashSet in my code, but that doesn't seem like a valid solution, since the choice of LinkedHashSet is simply to accommodate some test cases.

Is this a common situation in unit testing?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: HashSets are equal if they have the same size, and contain the same members. See [AbstractSet.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: What does the string representation have to do with comparing `Set`s for equality?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Of course such problems can be solved. But not input like this. We are no wizards here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> each time when I run the test case, my assertions may fail due to the different string representation value of `HashSet`.

This means that you should not use "raw" string representation of a `HashSet`.

If you would like to stick to comparing string representations, take an unordered hash set, sort it, and take string representation of the result. Make a helper method for converting a hash set to a string of ordered set components:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> String ordered(Set<T> set) {
    return set.stream().sorted().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

The string representation against which you compare should contain data that is sorted in the same order. Now comparison of the two strings should be repeatable:

```
assertEquals("1, 2, 3, 4, 5", ordered(obj.methodReturningHashSet()));
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/SZeS0c)

Comment: Isn't the OP asking how to compare sets for equality? "the value of this assertion comes from a `HashSet`"

Comment: And? So? Just assert equality of the sets. Order has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @LewBloch That's certainly one approach. Like most approaches in programming, it's not the only valid approach.

Answer (score 6):

Don't compare the `toString()` of a `HashSet<T>`, but compare it to another (expected) `HashSet<T>`.

The following test will succeed:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2, 1, 3));
    Set<Integer> expected = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(3, 2, 1));

    assertEquals(set, expected);
}
```

Comment: In my case, I have to assert a Set of a Matrix class to be a certain value, and it would be hard to create the "expected" hashset to compare. For me, the most convenient way to compare is to compare the String.

Answer (score 0):

**JUnit 5**

Testing if a Set contains one (or more) values, not considering the order:

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class OrderUpdateHelperTest {
   @Test
   void testSetUnorderedContents () {
      Set<EventType> expectedTypes = Helper.getExpectedTypes(OrderStatus.IN_PROGRESS);

      assertThat(expectedTypes).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(EventType.A, EventType.B);
   }
```